# Uniformly distribute elements in a cyclic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

I have encountered the following problem studying some practical applications of scheduling systems.

Given a set of symbol types *s1...sn* with associated frequencies of occurrence *f1..fn*, distribute the *f1+...+fn* symbols in a cyclic sequence such that uniformity in the distribution of each symbol type is maximized. *Uniformity* could be measured in several ways, a simple one would be to sum the squares of the distances (measured in intermediate symbols) of each symbol to the next symbol of the same type, for all symbol types. We would try to minimize this amount.

For example, if we have *s1=a, s2=b, f1=f2=2,* we would have a measure of uniformity for the sequence *abab* of 4 (remember that we are dealing with cyclic sequences), while for *aabb* we would have a measure of 8. It is easy to see that the first solution is optimal.

The approach seems simple and general enough to have been dealt with before, but I am finding it very difficult to relate it to other known problems. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much,

Daniel.